# Is SVG text selection not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

For some reason I can't get text selection of an SVG element to work in Chrome.

I had originally started with a PDF file that had been converted to SVG but when that did not work I thought it might be all the extra data within the SVG file. So then I very simple SVG examples like the one below but Chrome still apparently can't properly select the text. It works fine in other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="90" width="400">
    <text x="10" y="20" style="fill:red;">Several lines for testing:
        <tspan x="10" y="45">This is a sentance on the first line.</tspan>
        <tspan x="10" y="70">Testing a second line as well with text selection</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine in other browsers without any issues. I'm able to select each row individually or altogether without issues. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Chrome?

I need to be able to display converted SVG content within an HTML page and allow the user to select text if needed.

Comment: You may find this pen useful: [::selection and SVG text](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/VqMrPV)

Comment: This fix does not resolve the issue as the box highlight around the text is still broken. I'm not trying to change the text color while highlighting but resolve the issue where the cursors text selection box/rectangle does not work correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. In the pen linked you can see that .s::selection has background-color: indigo; In SVG you can use background properties only for the `<svg>` root  element.  You can't  use background properties for the text. I suppose chrome is the only browser that got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more digging it turns out this is a Chrome Regression issue reported in 70.0.3538.67.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897752#c27

According to the bug it will fixed in Chrome 72 (stable in February 2019).